# spark on yarn with springboot can not read the config files

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark

I'm trying to combine springboot and spark, but I can never read the configuration file.

I pass the configuration files belonging to spring by setting `--files applicatoin.properties` in the Spark-submit. However, it is not possible to read the contents of the file.

```bash
spark-submit other-config \
--class myclass \
--files /path/to/applicatoin.properties \
./my.jar
```

Spring logs: `No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile`. Other than that not seeing any other useful logs.

> As I understand it, `--files` passes the file to hdfs and the driver downloads it in a temporary path. The file should be in the same path as the running application, so reading the file in spark can be done with `./config.file` path.

When debugging in Idea, these configurations are read correctly. And if I pass the parameter: `--my.prop=111`, the program is able to read the configuration:

```bash
spark-submit other-config \
--class myclass \
./my.jar --my.prop=111
```

so the content should be fine.

Also, the configuration files I can't type into the jar as they should be modifiable.

Has anyone had this problem and how do I get this config file to be read.

Additional information:

> My initial goal was to use Spark as a backend server so that it could respond to requests (e.g. SQL, predefined models, etc.) more quickly, rather than waiting for a long spark-submit.
> During the implementation I was also thinking if combining springboot and spark is a good solution? The reason for choosing springboot is the simplicity of development.